# Linq to XML - Validate xml against dtd

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

I would like to validate the cXML Invoice against the DTD using Linq to XML or any C#. Could anyone please guide me how this can be achieved?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need LINQ for that. You'll find an example here;
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/xmlandnetfx/thread/782e8227-84aa-4e62-a77e-0801e8b8cb4c